# Java throwing exception when criteria not met

Tags: java, exception

I've been working on this program for the last week or so and have had this particular block of code running smoothly up until a little while ago. I haven't changed it at all, and all of a sudden it started throwing an exception for every option picked once the button was pushed. I've tested it for each option by putting a "System.out.println(activityMultiplier);" statement in each block, and it prints the correct value, so the item listener seems to be working. And when I select "Choose an Activity Level" (the optin which is supposed to throw an exception) the exception is thrown properly: the JOptionPane goes away once I click okay, and the JComboBox is still there so I can make another selection. However, I get the JOptionPane error message for EVERY option now,  I've included the noActivity() method at the bottom so you can see what I'm calling.

```
public void setActivity() //JComboBox
{
    final JFrame activityWindow = new JFrame();
    activityWindow.setTitle("Question No 6 of 6");
    activityWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel activityPanel = new JPanel();
    activityPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
    activityPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    JLabel activityLabel = new JLabel("Please select your activity level:");
    final JComboBox activityList = new JComboBox(activityString);

    activityList.setSelectedIndex(5);
    activityList.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            activityLevel = (String) activityList.getSelectedItem();
        }
    });

    JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
    submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (activityLevel.equals("Choose an activity level"))
                    throw new Exception();

                else if (activityLevel.equals("Sedentary (little or no exercise)"))
                {
                    activityMultiplier = 1.2;
                    activityWindow.dispose();
                    setBMR();
                }
                else if (activityLevel.equals("Lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/week)"))
                {
                    activityMultiplier = 1.375;
                    activityWindow.dispose();
                    System.out.println(activityMultiplier);
                    setBMR();
                }
                else if (activityLevel.equals("Moderatetely active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/week)"))
                {
                    activityMultiplier = 1.55;
                    activityWindow.dispose();
                    System.out.println(activityMultiplier);
                    setBMR();
                }
                else if (activityLevel.equals("Very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days a week"))
                {
                    activityMultiplier = 1.725;
                    activityWindow.dispose();
                    System.out.println(activityMultiplier);
                    setBMR();
                }
                else if (activityLevel.equals("Extra active (very hard exercise/sports & physical job or 2x/day training)"))
                {   activityMultiplier = 1.9;
                    activityWindow.dispose();
                    System.out.println(activityMultiplier);
                    setBMR();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {
                noActivity();
            }
        }
    });


    private void noActivity()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select an activity level.", "No Selection Made", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
    }
```

Comment: post your stack trace ??

Comment: Why do you throw an exception if you are gonna catch it inside the very same block? You can just call the `noActivity()` method directly instead. Also, it's bad form to catch generic exceptions.

Comment: What is `activityString` set to?  It looks like we don't have all of the code.

Comment: @mattforsythe activityString is set to an array of strings.  The strings are identical to the ones within my if-else statements: (e.g. "Choose a activity level", "Sedentary (little or no exercise)", etc).

Comment: @Boschman, do you mean just go ahead and do away with the try/catch chunks and go straight to the if else statements?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @ user35736644892 Also, I'm not sure what my stack trace is, or how to get it?

Comment: @St3v3-0 Yes, check out jambriz' answer. Indeed get rid of the try-catch altogether, you don't want to throw exceptions that you catch in the same method. Incidentally, I don't think that's the exception that's plaguing you, it's probably some other unrelated exception thrown in the `setBmr()` method. But paste `printStackTrace();` in the catch block for now and check the stack trace in the error message, it will tell you the exact line the error occurred on.

Comment: I don't feel 100% confident about this (if for no other reason than I'm a complete n00b) but my program seems to be working again. It did seem like the issue was some sort of generic exception issue as @Boschman mentioned.  I tried a whole bunch of tests, including just commenting out the new code down below which is what seemed to have kicked off my problems. That didn't work, so I ended up copying/pasting all of my code into a new project, deleting the suspicious code prior to compiling, changing the exception to a NullPointerException. Seems to be working.

Comment: I wish I were more versed in reading the stackTrace stuff because I was able to paste it into my catch block and see which lines were causing issues.  However, what it pointed to didn't really clarify anything for me. Guess that means I need to study more. :-) Thanks a bunch for all the insanely prompt responses. The was my first question and I didn't expect so much interest.  I'm still new to this forum so please let me know if I need to give props to someone.

Answer (score 1):

why not simply change it to:

```
 if (activityLevel.equals("Choose an activity level"))
          noActivity();
```

the rest of the options are in else if blocks anyway
i don't think that is a proper use for an Exception

Comment: I fully agree, already posted a comment about this. However, I doubt it will solve the problem, it looks to me like some other unrelated exception occurs that gets caught in the generic catch.

Comment: @jambriz and Boschman, I got rid of the try/catch parts of the code and simply called the noActivity() method as you've got it posted above. No dice. This time I actually get runtime errors, which did not happen before. I had no errors, it just wasn't working right.

Comment: @Boschman, I think you're onto something. When this error first started occurring was right after I added another method down below which includes a FileNotFoundException. Hopefully I post this correctly

``try
  {
   inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileIn));
   outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileOut);
  } 
  catch(FileNotFoundException e3)
  {
   fileNotFound();
  }``

Comment: Sorry, I'm having issues formatting my code snippet there.

Comment: its not that the runtime<b>exceptions</b> didnt happen before, you were catching everything, and handling it as if it were your exception. thats why someone suggested to print the stacktrace to find out why the catch block is executing